# How to load a docker image using tar.gz file in google compute engine?

Tags: linux, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to run the following command on google compute engine instance the tar.gz file is large 24GB, and I am using 8 cores 32GB CE with 100GB storage. Whenever i run the following command my prompt get's stuck(It gives no output/no standard output which is very annoying) and i have no ways to know what's happening with command. I did run the same command on my localhost and successfully spin up the container. I am not sure how long to wait as there is no feedback in std out.

```
docker load -i cnt7-jarvis-cdh63.tar.gz
```

Comment: Can you push the image to GCR?  You should not normally need `docker load`, particularly in a cloud environment that already has a hosted Docker registry.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [screen](https://www.howtogeek.com/662422/how-to-use-linuxs-screen-command/) to run this process in background:

```
screen
docker load -i cnt7-jarvis-cdh63.tar.gz
```

Then detach (do not press Enter after these keys):

```
Ctrl+A
d
```

And check resource usage:

```
top
```

After process has completed you can go back to that screen:

```
screen -ls
screen -r <NUMBER>
```